# FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 381 When try to delete image

Tags: laravel-5

i'm bulding simple insert and delete function using laravel 5.0

However it give me an error :

FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 381:
File not found at path: public/img/products/xxxxxx.xxx

My Code is :

```
 public function postCreate(Requests\ProductRequest $request)
{
    $product = new Product;
    $product->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
    $product->title = Input::get('title');
    $product->description = Input::get('description');
    $product->price = Input::get('price');
    $product->status = Input::get('status');

    $image = Input::file('image');
    $filename  = date('m-d-Y-H_i_s')."-". $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
    $product->image = 'img/products/'.$filename;
    $product->save();
    return redirect('admin/products/')->with('flash_message','Product created');
}

public function postDestroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    if ($product) {
        Storage::delete('public/'.$product->image);
        $product->delete();
        return redirect('admin/products')->with('flash_message', 'Product deleted');
    }
    return redirect('admin/products')->with('flash_message','Something went wrong , please try again');
}
```

May i know what happen? i try few alternatives such :

File::delete (no error but image not deleted)
\File::delete (no error but image not deleted)

Namespace :

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use File;
```

Comment: When saving, you are using `public_path(...)`, try to use it when deleting file (instead of `'public/' . $product->image`).

Answer (score 3):

5 months later I stumble on to the same exception using Laravel 5.1. Using `Storage::delete()`, I tried passing it the relative path to my delete target file from the root of the storage folder, and that failed with file not found. In the stack trace I saw that Filesystem->delete was being called with an invalid path relative to the physical machine's path. So I called it with `storage_path().'/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG'`

That's when the stack trace got interesting. When I called it with the full true file system path, it still threw a filenotfoundexception, but the path shown as passed to `Filesystem->assertPresent()` had the leading slash peeled off. Like so:

1. in Filesystem.php line 381
2. at `Filesystem->assertPresent('home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG')` in Filesystem.php line 232
3. at `Filesystem->delete('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG')` in FilesystemAdapter.php line 155
4. at `FilesystemAdapter->delete('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG')`
5. at `call_user_func_array(array(object(FilesystemAdapter), 'delete'), array('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG'))` in FilesystemManager.php line 293
6. at `FilesystemManager->__call('delete', array('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG'))` in Facade.php line 216
7. at `FilesystemManager->delete('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG')` in Facade.php line 216
8. at `Facade::__callStatic('delete', array('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG'))` in ObservationsController.php line 224
9. at `Storage::delete('/home/vagrant/Proj/donk/storage/app/7/observe/1455749755-yet.JPG')` in ObservationsController.php line 224

The path at line 3 of the stack trace, `Filesystem->delete()` is dead on. But what is passed to actually check file existence `[assertPresent()]` is relative, and in this case not a valid path.

My workaround was to simply use `File::delete()` rather than Storage::delete(). Perhaps the latter can work when it's a file that's sitting at the root of the storage folder, but I'm not going to bother testing that because that's not what I want to do. If that's the limitation of the Storage class, it's not worth much IMO.

Found this interesting related thread at github. Apparently it's by design? Seems, uh, flawed.

https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/477

Comment: By default the folder is storage/app you need to get file from there
if your file is located somewhere else you can make your own disk in config/filesystems e.g. `'myDisk' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>base_path('xyzFolder'),
        ],`

and you can call it like

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

    $data = Storage::disk('myDisk')->get('myFile.txt');

this is obviously to get file and you can perform any other function by following laravel docs.